# lodown R package issue with PNS data

Tags: r, survey

first time asking question in stackoverflow.

I'm trying to follow the examples regarding the PNS (Pesquisa Nacional de Saúde) via lodown R package (instructions in the book http://asdfree.com/). I'm following the code to the letter but I keep getting error messages. This is the code and output error message that I get from R together with my sessionInfo(). Is there a way to get the data? I don't understand the error message that I'm getting.

```
pns_cat <- lodown("pns" , pns_cat)
locally downloading pns

downloading from URL
'ftp://ftp.ibge.gov.br/PNS/2019/Microdados/Documentacao'
to file
'C:\Users\dcpca\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpuO2Oba\file512c18947'

download issue with
'ftp://ftp.ibge.gov.br/PNS/2019/Microdados/Documentacao'

download issue with
'ftp://ftp.ibge.gov.br/PNS/2019/Microdados/Documentacao'

download issue with
'ftp://ftp.ibge.gov.br/PNS/2019/Microdados/Documentacao'

R version 4.0.1 (2020-06-06)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19041)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Portuguese_Brazil.1252  LC_CTYPE=Portuguese_Brazil.1252    LC_MONETARY=Portuguese_Brazil.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                       LC_TIME=Portuguese_Brazil.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] forcats_0.5.1     stringr_1.4.0     dplyr_1.0.3       purrr_0.3.4       readr_1.4.0       tidyr_1.1.2      
 [7] tibble_3.0.5      ggplot2_3.3.3     tidyverse_1.3.0   SAScii_1.0        lodown_0.1.0      srvyr_1.0.0      
[13] survey_4.0        survival_3.1-12   Matrix_1.2-18     data.table_1.13.6 devtools_2.3.2    usethis_2.0.0    
[19] pacman_0.5.1     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.6        lubridate_1.7.9.2 lattice_0.20-41   prettyunits_1.1.1 ps_1.5.0          digest_0.6.27    
 [7] assertthat_0.2.1  rprojroot_2.0.2   cellranger_1.1.0  R6_2.5.0          backports_1.2.0   reprex_1.0.0     
[13] httr_1.4.2        pillar_1.4.7      rlang_0.4.10      curl_4.3          readxl_1.3.1      rstudioapi_0.13  
[19] callr_3.5.1       desc_1.2.0        splines_4.0.1     RCurl_1.98-1.2    munsell_0.5.0     broom_0.7.4      
[25] compiler_4.0.1    modelr_0.1.8      pkgconfig_2.0.3   pkgbuild_1.2.0    mitools_2.4       tidyselect_1.1.0 
[31] crayon_1.4.0      dbplyr_2.0.0      withr_2.4.1       bitops_1.0-6      jsonlite_1.7.2    gtable_0.3.0     
[37] lifecycle_0.2.0   DBI_1.1.1         magrittr_2.0.1    scales_1.1.1      stringi_1.5.3     cli_2.3.0        
[43] cachem_1.0.1      fs_1.5.0          remotes_2.2.0     testthat_3.0.1    xml2_1.3.2        ellipsis_0.3.1   
[49] generics_0.1.0    vctrs_0.3.6       tools_4.0.1       glue_1.4.2        hms_1.0.0         processx_3.4.5   
[55] pkgload_1.1.0     fastmap_1.1.0     colorspace_2.0-0  sessioninfo_1.1.1 rvest_0.3.6       memoise_2.0.0    
[61] haven_2.3.1      


lodown is now exiting unexpectedly.
websites that host publicly-downloadable microdata change often and sometimes those changes cause this software to break.
if the error call stack below appears to be a hiccup in your internet connection, then please verify your connectivity and retry the download.
otherwise, please open a new issue at `https://github.com/ajdamico/asdfree/issues` with the contents of this error call stack and also the output of your `sessionInfo()`.


[[1]]
lodown("pns", pns_cat)

[[2]]
withCallingHandlers(catalog <- load_fun(data_name = data_name, 
    catalog, ...), error = function(e) {
    print(sessionInfo())
    if (grepl("cannot allocate vector of size", e)) 
        message(memory_note)
    else if (grepl("parameter must be specified", e)) 
        message(parameter_note)
    else if (grepl("to install", e)) 
        message(installation_note)
    else {
        message(unknown_error_note)
        print(sys.calls())
    }
})

[[3]]
load_fun(data_name = data_name, catalog, ...)

[[4]]
cachaca(catalog[i, "full_url"], tf, mode = "wb")

[[5]]
httr_filesize(this_url, attempts, sleepsec)

[[6]]
stop(paste0("httr::HEAD( '", url, "' )\nfailed after ", 
    initial.attempts, " attempts"))

[[7]]
.handleSimpleError(function (e) 
{
    print(sessionInfo())
    if (grepl("cannot allocate vector of size", e)) 
        message(memory_note)
    else if (grepl("parameter must be specified", e)) 
        message(parameter_note)
    else if (grepl("to install", e)) 
        message(installation_note)
    else {
        message(unknown_error_note)
        print(sys.calls())
    }
}, "httr::HEAD( 'ftp://ftp.ibge.gov.br/PNS/2019/Microdados/Documentacao' )\nfailed after 3 attempts", 
    base::quote(httr_filesize(this_url, attempts, sleepsec)))

[[8]]
h(simpleError(msg, call))

Error in httr_filesize(this_url, attempts, sleepsec) : 
  httr::HEAD( 'ftp://ftp.ibge.gov.br/PNS/2019/Microdados/Documentacao' )
failed after 3 attempts
  year                                                                                         full_url
1 2019                                           ftp://ftp.ibge.gov.br/PNS/2019/Microdados/Documentacao
2 2013 ftp://ftp.ibge.gov.br/PNS/2013/Microdados/historico_atualizacao_microdados_PNS_2013_20200825.txt
                  output_folder                          long_file                          all_file
1 C:/Users/dcpca/Documents/PNS/ 2019 long questionnaire survey.rds 2019 all questionnaire survey.rds
2 C:/Users/dcpca/Documents/PNS/ 2013 long questionnaire survey.rds 2013 all questionnaire survey.rds
                                long_design                               all_design case_count
1 2019 long questionnaire survey design.rds 2019 all questionnaire survey design.rds         NA
2 2013 long questionnaire survey design.rds 2013 all questionnaire survey design.rds         NA
```

Comment: Did you see in the error message where it says **please open a new issue at...** Did you check the GitHub site for info? Did you see **httr:: ... failed after 3 attempts**  What does that tell you?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's been some time, but I'm gonna answer my own question. I tried to get in touch with the maintainer of lodown but without success. In the mean time, a very nice package was released to get the PNS data from IBGE. The package is called "PNSIBGE" if this is of interest to anyone.

```
install.packages("PNSIBGE")
```